# Write data to two SQL databases from Entity Framework in c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having an issue with my website(ASP.NET, c#, SQL, Code-first Entity Framework).

I have a project with an attached SQL database generated from code first entity framework.

Now I have imported another SQL database using model first database which looks almost same but the table and column names are different.

So now I would like to write data to two databases at the same time with just one click from my web application.

The newly attached database will be a backup and we should write data to both databases at the same time.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just create two contexts. One for each database.

Comment: Create your DataContext using the database and whenever you want to write to a different database, initiate that context with a different connection string. You can write to as many databases as you like.

Comment: Well, I got two contexts already, but I am confused to how to match entities from two databases at the same time.

Comment: can you please give me an example if you can, @MattRowland

Comment: As I got a bunch of tables, I need a match between tables, which a table maps to the corresponding table in other database.

Comment: EF won't do that for you. You will have to create methods to map them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you need to do the mapping yourself, but one thing I would like to add, you may need to wrap your SaveChanges() into a transaction, you may find steps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx